# Wrong indentation in brackets

Tags: indentation, cursor, filetype-python

How can I change the automatic indentation inside brackets? Without any configuration, {vim,nvim} does the following:

```python
test = [| # Press enter
```

```python
test = [
        | # Cursor ends up here, at the same level as the opening bracket
```

Here's what I'd like to get:

```python
test = [
    | # Cursor should end up here, with one more indentation level than the previous line
```

Treesitter indentation doesn't seem to help.

This happens in python files amongst others (i.e. `filetype=python`)

Comment: The configuration is usually per filetype. What is the filetype of your buffer `:set ft?`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt this happens in python files amongst others (i.e. `filetype=python`)

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question (e.g. other file types for which you search a solution)? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This automatic indentation is controlled by the `indentexpr` option.

For python the default procedure is configurable and if you set the following global variable `g:pyindent_open_paren` to `shiftwidth()` you'll get the behavior your want:

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren = shiftwidth()
```

More information with: `:help ft-python-indent`